# Interface method referencing same interface?

Tags: go, interface, polymorphism

i'm a java programer ,i'm learing go now.
i try to wirte a self nested interface named Vo,and a implemention of Vo named Score,
code like this:

```
type Vo interface {
        Merge(v Vo) Vo
}

type Score int

func (this Score) Merge(s Score) Score {
    return Score(this + s)
}

func TestThePkg(t *testing.T) {
    s := Score(5)
    var v Vo = s //compile error
}
```

detail compile error is :

```
cannot use s (variable of type Score) as Vo value in variable declaration: Score does not implement Vo (wrong type for method Merge)
        have Merge(s Score) Score
        want Merge(v Vo) VocompilerInvalidIfaceAssign
```

how to resolve this problem?
thanks!

Comment: See https://go.dev/doc/faq#covariant_types. From Go1.18 you can use [*type parameters*](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_parameter_declarations) though, which may, or may not, get you the result you are looking for: https://go.dev/play/p/fnNsu2m7YFF

Comment: func (s Score) Merge(v Vo) Vo

Comment: yeah!!! it  work well !   thank you very much! i get a lots  from you!

Comment: but if i want  vo1.Merge(vo2), it not work! so ,how do i thinks about go 's semantic of interface when using polymorphism

Comment: i think an interface is an abstract from various  concrete types，so ,a concrete types should not know the existence of the abstract interface. but ,obviously go dose not support this idea thoroughly  . go dose not separate abstract from concrete completely . that is，  in a  concrete types ,i must use the abstract interface as the concrete type  parameter  when  the concrete type's  methods operate itself . otherwise ,it will not conform the semantic of the abstract interface。

Answer (score 0):

[play ground](https://go.dev/play/p/TuQImxWAkIe)

```
func (this Score) Merge(s Vo) Vo {
    if typeAssersion, ok := s.(Score); ok {
        return Score(this + typeAssersion)
    }
    //log err or the `Vo` interface should return (Vo,error)
    return nil
}
```